# How to store count of items in useInfiniteQuery in react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I am using `@tanstack/react-query` library in my React app which renders paginated list of items. `GET /api/items?page=0` returns something like this:

```js
{
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 20,
    totalCount: 345,
    items: ["item1", "item2", ...]

}
```

I am using `useInfiniteQuery` for fetching those data:

```js
const { data } = useInfiniteQuery({
    getNextPageParam: lastPage => lastPage.page + 1,
    queryFn: async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => fetch(`/api/items?page=${pageParam}`)
})
```

However, then the data structure looks like this:

```js
[
    pageParams: [0, 1, 2],
    pages: [
       { page: 0, pageSize: 20, totalCount: 345, items: [...] },
       { page: 1, pageSize: 20, totalCount: 345, items: [...] },
       { page: 2, pageSize: 20, totalCount: 345, items: [...] },
    ]
]
```

`totalCount` information is in each page. So now if user deletes one item, I need to update all the pages to make it consistent (totalCount: 345 -> 344). Is there any way how to store some information across all pages of `useInfiniteQuery`, so I can update it at one place?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about [Query Invalidation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/guides/query-invalidation), but I'm not entirely sure if it's the right solution for you

When you invalidate a query by its key, every loaded page of your `GET /api/items` request will be refetched.

The `totalCount` will be updated throughout the entire data structure. However, if the data changes while the query is refetching, it's not guaranteed that the `totalCount` value will remain consistent across all pages